# Tracking clicks using both Webtrends + Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, webtrends

I need to track clicks to a webpage that already has Webtrends codes embedded. The thing is that I also need to track clicks to that page using Google Analytics.

It would have been easy if I can just embed Google Analytics's code on to the landing webpage but my client does not allow us to modify their webpage.

My question now is that, is it possible to track clicks on both Webtrends and Google Analytics by placing two tracking parameters (or syntax; query) onto one single URL?

For example:

http://example.com/adredirect.php?WT.mc_id=XXXXXXX?utm_source=XXX&utm_medium=XXX&utm_campaign=XXX

Within the "adredirect.php" page, I then can embed our GA code inside, with a redirect code to the correct landing page. I know for sure that by clicking the link above it will lead the browser to my desired page. What I don't know is that will the two parameters be actually captured correctly by both GA and Webtrends?

Are there other ways to achieve similar tasks?

Thanks to all that have time to help.

Regards!

Comment: Have you tried looking clicking that link and looking to see if it showed up in the real-time reports?

Comment: There are two question marks in your example so this won't work no matter what ("?" is wat separates the query string from the url, "&" is the delimiter between parameters). However I'm not quite sure what you are asking, if you cannot place tracking code on your clients webpage you cannot track traffic there.